# Problema al editar una fila

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-hoja-de-cálculo, requests

estoy realizando una web que se comunica con una hoja de google sheets. El problema es cuando quiero editar el contenido de una fila para que no se muestre al usuario si cumple con una determinada condicion. La funcion quiere editar la fila "statusJob" al hacer click en el boton "finish" cambiar el contenido de la casilla a 'FINALIZADO' y que no se muestre al usuario esa fila.

aca les comparto los archivos index y sheets que son donde puede estar el problema, gracias de antemano por su tiempo. Al final les coloco el error que me arroja. Gracias.

index.js

```
const framesContainer = document.getElementById("framesContainer");
const detailContainer = document.getElementById("detailContainer");
let indexSelect;

const clientElement = document.getElementById("client");
const modelElement = document.getElementById("model");
const problemElement = document.getElementById("problem");
const commentElement = document.getElementById("comment");
const finishElement = document.getElementById("finish");


function createJob(frame,index){
  const newJob = document.createElement("div");
  newJob.classList = "job";
  newJob.innerHTML = `
    <h3>${frame.frame_job}</h3>
    <p>${frame.box}</p>
    <p>${frame.statusJob}</p>
    <p>${frame.last_update}</p>
  `
  newJob.addEventListener("click", ()=> actDetail(index))
  framesContainer.appendChild(newJob);
}

function actJob(){
  framesContainer.innerHTML = "";
  frames.forEach((frame,i) => {
    createJob(frame,i);
  })
}

function actDetail(index){
  if(indexSelect !== undefined) framesContainer.children[indexSelect].classList.toggle("select",false);
  clientElement.innerText = frames[index].frame_job;
  modelElement.innerText = frames[index].box;
  problemElement.innerText = frames[index].statusJob;
  commentElement.innerText = frames[index].last_update;
  detailContainer.classList.toggle("hidden",false);
  indexSelect = index;
  framesContainer.children[indexSelect].classList.toggle("select",true);
}


finish.addEventListener("click",()=> finishUpdate(indexSelect))

async function finishUpdate(i){
  const updateFrame = frames[i];
  updateFrame.statusJob = 'FINALIZADO';
  const res = await editFrame(updateFrame.id,updateFrame);
  if(res.status === 200){
    framesContainer = framesContainer.filter(frame => frame.id != updateFrame.id);
    indexSelect = 0;
    actJob();
    detailContainer.classList.toggle("hidden",true);
  }
}
```

```
sheets.js

    const sheet = "Armazones";
    let frames;
    let dateNow = new Date();
    let hour = dateNow.getHours();
    let minutes = dateNow.getMinutes();
    let seconds = dateNow.getSeconds();
    
    async function getframes() {
      let response;
      try {
        response = await gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET,
          range: sheet + "!A1:F",
        });
      } catch (err) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerText = err.message;
        return;
      }
    
      const range = response.result;
      if (!range || !range.values || range.values.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerText = "No values found.";
        return;
      }
    
    
      frames = [];
      range.values.forEach((fila) => {
        // Obtiene el contenido de las celdas 1 y 4
        const frame_job = fila[1];
        const glasses = fila[4];
    
        // Compara frame_job con glasses
        if (frame_job === glasses || glasses === frame_job) {
          // Cambia el estado del trabajo
          fila[3] = "FINALIZAR";
        }
      });
      range.values.forEach((fila) => {
        // let indexNum = value4.indexOf(value1);
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(fila[1])) && fila[3] !== "FINALIZADO") {;
        // if (indexNum > -1) {fila[3] = "POR FINALIZAR"}
        const newFrame = {
          manager: fila[0],
          frame_job: fila[1],
          box: fila[2],
          statusJob: fila[3],
          glasses: fila[4],
          last_update: fila[5]
        };
        frames.push(newFrame);
      }
      });
      console.log(range.values);
    
    }
    
    
    
    async function editFrame(id, content) {
      const update = [
        content.manager,
        content.frame_job,
        content.box,
        content.statusJob,
        content.glasses,
        new Date().toISOString(),
      ]
      const editRow = parseInt(content.id) + 1;
      response = await gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
        spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET,
        range: `${sheet}!A${editRow}:${editRow}`,
        values: [update],
        valueInputOption:"USER_ENTERED",
      });
      return response;
    }


ESTE ES EL ERROR QUE ME ARROJA:

error: 
code: 400
message: "Unable to parse range: Armazones!ANaN:NaN"
status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
[[Prototype]]: 
Object
[[Prototype]]: 
Object
status: 400
statusText: null
```

Comment: Yo que tu miraría qué te está llegando en ese `content.id` porque es obvio que no es lo que tu imaginas, pues está devolviendo `NaN`, not a number. No podemos ayudarte sin saber qué valores tienen los parámetros, depura y edita la pregunta para incluirlos, aunque es posible que al hacerlo puedas arreglarlo sin más...

Comment: Gracias amigo, tenias estaba llamando un atributo que no existia. Ya lo solucione, gracias nuevamente por tu tiempo.